# Is there way to customize PnP modern people search so it displays more than 1 column of people

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, pnp, people-search

I am using PnP modern search v4.4.1 and was wondering if there was a way I can make 2 column or result appear instead of 1 column as following:

[image]